# PHP append each element in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, onesignal

I'm having a difficult time appending each element in an array I have in PHP for multiple OneSignal tags. Here is the result of my current JSON encoded array:

```
[{"value":"email@address.com"},
{"value":"email@address.com"},
{"value":"email@address.com"}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@address.com"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@address.com"},
{"key":"user_email","relation":"=","value":"email@address.com"}]
```

Here is my current PHP code:

```
 $jsonData = array();

 $allStaffInit = mysql_query("Select * from users");

 while ($staffrow = mysql_fetch_object($allStaffInit)){

   $jsonData[] = $staffrow;  

 }

 echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: `$jsondata[] = array('key'=>$key,'relation'=>$rel,'value' => $val);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$jsonData[] = $staffrow;
```

with

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->key = "user_email";
$object->relation = "=";
$object->value = $staffrow->value;

$jsonData[] = $object;
```

I am typing this in a browser, so cannot test, but you get the idea (if you don't get the idea, ask in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the `mysql_` functions, you don't need to manually construct an object or array, just get the result set as an array and use that.

```
while ($staffrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($allStaffInit)){
    $jsonData[] = $staffRow;
}
```

But I seriously recommend you at least upgrade to using the `mysqli` extension instead. You won't really have to adjust your code much.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php